# django ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have an issue with my site, receiving this error pretty often.
It's the first time i've run into this and maybe someone can shed some light as to why?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/www/django_test1/fundedbyme/project/views.py", line 194, in browse
items = Project.objects.filter(categories__slug=cat_name, status='AP')[:count]

File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 151, in __getitem__
stop = int(k.stop)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

**Here is my view.**

```
def browse(request, template_name='projects/browse.html'):
    cat_name = request.GET.get('category', None)
    city_name = request.GET.get('city', None)
    count = request.GET.get('count','12')
    if cat_name is not None:
        items = Project.objects.filter(categories__slug=cat_name, status='AP')[:count]
        category = get_object_or_None(Category, slug=cat_name)
    if city_name is not None:
        items = Project.objects.filter(location_slug=city_name, status='AP')[:count]
        category = Project.objects.filter(location_slug=city_name, status='AP')[:1]
        category = category[0].location
    total = items.count()
    new_count = int(count) + 12

    context = {'items':items,'cat_name':category,'total':total,'new_count':new_count,}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count` is the empty string. You need to compensate for the possibility that `count` could be a non-integer string.

Comment: thanks for the message. I'll try and do a workaround then instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check URL in your template.
you need to pass the integer id to url {{user.id}} because url need to have integer value in template.
Ex.  url:-  /polls/{{user.id}}/

And in template first check your getting id or not like anywhere in template type  sdhajdhgsjgd {{user.id}} kejhksdbjf   and check your getting the integer value or not.

Hope this will work for others.